# Is it safe to use CString::GetString() with CWnd::SendMessage()?

Tags: visual-c++, casting, mfc, c-strings, postmessage

I have this code:

```
GetParent()->SendMessage(UWM_DELETE_NAME_HISTORY_MSG, (WPARAM)strName.GetBufferSetLength(_MAX_PATH));
strName.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Is it safe for me to change it like this:

```
GetParent()->SendMessage(UWM_DELETE_NAME_HISTORY_MSG, (WPARAM)strName.GetString());
```

Related to this, is it correct to use `static_cast<WPARAM>(strName.GetString())`?

---

For completion, this is my custom message handler:

```
LRESULT CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnDeleteNameHistory(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    auto szName = (LPCTSTR)wParam;

    m_History.erase(szName);

    for (auto& kv : m_mapWeekendHistData)
        kv.second.erase(szName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what the message handler for UWM_DELETE_NAME_HISTORY_MSG does.

Comment: Title says PostMessage, and the question asks SendMessage, make up your mind, Post may be unsafe when Send safe

Comment: `static_cast<WPARAM>(strName.GetString())` won't compile. You'll need a `reinterpret_cast` to go from a pointer to a WPARAM. And yes, you need to do that sort of `reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(string)` quite a lot with standard Windows messages that take a `char*` for their Lparam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SendMessage` is a blocking call. Once it returns, it no longer needs access to its arguments. With that in mind

```cpp
GetParent()->SendMessage(UWM_DELETE_NAME_HISTORY_MSG, (WPARAM)strName.GetString());
```

is safe (as far as the `SendMessage` call is concerned).

You'd still need to be careful about the implementer of the `UWM_DELETE_NAME_HISTORY_MSG` message (which, presumably, is a custom message). If the implementation stores a pointer and uses it after the handler has run to completion, then that is an issue that needs to be resolved.

In general, if you implement a message handler, you should follow the Windows API's core principles. There are ultimately two implementation:

- Store a copy of client-provided data (such as [`SetWindowTextW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw)).
- Return a reference to the previous value in case the API takes ownership of the client-provided data (such as [`SelectObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject)).

Comment: Thanks. I have added my custom message handler for completeness. I think it is all OK now. The only difference being that I have used `reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title:

> Is it safe to use CString::GetString() with CWnd::POstMessage()?

No, it is not - the content of that `CString` may be reallocated or deleted by the time the message will be processed.

Comment: My title meant to say SendMessage. Sorry for that oversight on my part.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle oh, then it is answered in the comments.